# Referencing a class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the error "'ToDataTable' is not a member of 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage'." on this line "GridView1.DataSource = package.ToDataTable()" and can't determine why my code can't find this class.

Default.aspx.vb:

```
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports WebFormsTest

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

        If Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) = ".xlsx" Then
            Dim package As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.FileContent)
            GridView1.DataSource = package.ToDataTable()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

ExcelPackageExtensions.vb

```
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace WebFormsTest
Public Class ExcelPackageExtensions
    Function ToDataTable(ByVal package As ExcelPackage) As DataTable
        Dim workSheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First()
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()

        For Each firstRowCell In workSheet.Cells(1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.[End].Column)
            table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text)
        Next

        For rowNumber = 2 To workSheet.Dimension.[End].Row
            Dim row = workSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.[End].Column)
            Dim newRow = table.NewRow()

            For Each cell In row
                newRow(cell.Start.Column - 1) = cell.Text
            Next

            table.Rows.Add(newRow)
        Next

        Return table
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: It's not a member of that class, so why would that error message be a surprise? If you're intending for `ToDataTable` to be an extension method, even though you haven't mentioned that anywhere in your question, then you ought to learn how to write extension methods first. It doesn't just happen by magic. The method MUST be declared in a module and it MUST have the `ExtensionAttribute` applied. As it stands, it's a regular instance method and needs to be called that way, i.e. by creating an instance of `ExcelPackageExtensions`, calling the method on that and passing an `ExcelPackage` argument.

Comment: In your previous question you did declare it properly, so now I really don't know what you're trying to achieve. Now it's no longer an extension method but that doesn't make it a member of the class you were trying to extend. Try explaining what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: Seems like you could use OleDb to get your DataTable.

Comment: I'm trying to convert this c# example to VB.net since my whole project is in VB. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/277/reading-excel-files-without-saving-to-disk-in-asp-net I created a new project in C# for testing and it works fine but can't get it to work in VB.  I can't use OleDb any longer for security issues at work.

Comment: Copy the code of the example and paste it into any [converter](https://converter.telerik.com/) and you will get a proper extension method result

Comment: "Copy the code of the example and paste it into any converter" - that's exactly what I did.